# Resultado diferente entre select, após aplicar o SUM() e o Grop By

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou fazendo um relatório de ligações do elastix e estou com um problema aqui no resultado.
Teoricamente, se eu não mexe no `Where`, o resultado teria que ser o mesmo.

```sql
select distinct
(case left( devices.id ,2)
when '10' then 'SAC'
when '40' then 'SAC'
when '41' then 'SAC'
when '80' then 'OUTROS'
when '70' then 'OUTROS'
when '90' then 'RECEPCAO'
when '91' then 'ADMINISTRATIVO'
when '92' then 'COMERCIAL'
when '93' then 'T.I.'
when '95' then 'SAC'
when '98' then 'PROJETOS'
when '99' then 'DIRETORIA DE T.I.'
else ' ' end) AS  grupo ,
round(sum(cdr.duration)/60)   AS  "duracao

from ((cdr  join  devices  on(( devices.dial  = substring_index(cdr.channel ,'-',1))))
join  trunks  on((substring_index(cdr.lastdata ,'/',2) = substring_index( trunks.channelid ,'/',2))))

where outcid = '12121212' and
!(left(cdr.dst,4) = 0800) and
(char_length(cdr.dst) > 4) and
cdr.duration > 60 and calldate >= '2014-02-01' and calldate <=  '2014-02-20'
group by grupo with rollup;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Você não alterou o where mas alterou todo o result set por usar um aggregate, no caso o SUM. Sim o resultado deverá ser diferente. Além do mais edite sua questão ela não ficou muito clara. Pelo que entendi você usa um select para retornar o grid e outro, com o somatório de durações por departamento. Mas não ficou claro qual o seu objetivo. PS:. no print seu total agregado está o dobro do mostrado no detalhado.

Comment: PS2: Você não precisa do distinct, o group by já vai retornar apenas um row por grupo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você define `group by grupo` Você solicita que o mysql exiba os seus resultados agrupados, isto é, irá haver apenas um retorno para cada tipo de grupo.

E o `SUM()` faz a soma dos valores "duração" de cada um dos itens que compões cada grupo.

Ao invéz de usar o `distinct`, reveja o uso que está fazendo dos joins, na intenção de evitar itens duplicados.

Fora isso, não consegui identificar exatamente qual seria a sua dúvida.

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme por tentar ajudar.
Eu tenho um Select e ele me traz o resultado do primeiro grid e quando eu aplico o sum() e o group by, o resultado é outro conforme o print.
Tem como me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: os dois selects são exatamente iguais exceto pelo group by e pelo sum()? você já tentou fazer um teste sem utilizar esses join's?
Uma query simplificada nos ajudaria a entender o seu caso já que não conhecemos a estrutura do seu banco...

Comment: de qualquer modo sugiro que você atualize o a sua pergunta, para deixar mais claro o que você precisa, evitando assim que sua pergunta seja fechada.

Comment: Olá Guilherme.
Eu refiz os dois select's e agora, está dando uma diferença de 4 min.
Gostaria de saber como eu faço para resolver isso.
Vou postar os dois select's.
Obrigado.

Comment: Segue Where do relatório:
FROM cdr a, devices b
where b.dial  = substring_index(a.channel ,'-',1) and
!(left(a.dst,4) = 0800) and
(char_length(a.dst) > 7) and
(char_length(a.clid) > 7) and
a.clid = '22164000' and
a.duration  > 60 and
!(b.id = '9501') and
a.calldate between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-21' ;

Comment: Where do Totalizador de minutos por setor:
FROM cdr a, devices b
where b.dial  = substring_index(a.channel ,'-',1) and
!(left(a.dst,4) = 0800) and
(char_length(a.dst) > 7) and
(char_length(a.clid) > 7) and
a.clid = operadora and
a.duration > 60 and
!(b.id = '9501') and
a.calldate between datainicial and datafinal
group by grupo;

Comment: Não coloquei o Select completo devido a limitação da quantidade de caracteres.
Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado.
Está funcionando. Usei letra para apelidar as tabelas (FROM cdr a, devices b where) e retirei o distinct.

Comment: cara, dá um update na sua própria questão, assim as querys ficaram visíveis para todos, e caso tenha encontrado a solução, dê um UPDATE mencionando isso.

Comment: Guilherme, eu coloquei no post anterior que estava funcionando.
Obrigado a todos.