# Soma de um resultado de um SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de relatório para controle de ligações e preciso pegar o resultado de uma consulta e fazer um somatório que me traga o total de ligações por setor de um determinado número.

Estou usando `Stored Procedure` com banco MySQL e o desenvolvimento é em ASP.Net.
Estou tentando da seguinte forma.

Declarei as variáveis recebendo zero:

```
Double TotalLigacoes, TotalSetor, TotalSac, TotalProjetos, TotalTI, TotalADMINISTRATIVO, TotalComercial, TotalDiretoria, TotalRecepcao, TotalOutros = 0;

protected void GvSetor_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.Cells.[0].text == "ADMINISTRATIVO")
    {
        TotalADM = TotalADM + Convert.ToDouble( TotalADM + e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
    }
}
```

Tenho que fazer algo como um looping para somar os minutos de `SqlDataSource  (Separado por setor) e soma em um variável para exibir no outro grid.

Comment: Mas qual o seu problema? Deu algum erro?

Comment: `TotalADM` não foi declarado. Seria `TotalADMINISTRATIVO`?

Comment: Desculpa.
Eu alterei mas quando postei, postei errado.

Comment: O problema é que não sei como resolver isso e esta dando um erro.
Indetifier expected.
Como eu coloco o Print aqui?
Obrigado.

Comment: @fabricio_wm http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Tinha um ponto antes do colchetes no if.
Mas esta retornando zero.

Answer (score 2):

`TotalADM = TotalADM + Convert.ToDouble( TotalADM + e.Row.Cells[1].Text);`

Com isso você está somando TotalADM duas vezes. Faça assim:

`TotalADM += Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);`

Comment: Dessa forma, eu vou somar só os minutos do setor administrativo?
Não precisa de nenhum looping?

Comment: protected void GvRelatorio_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
 
 if(e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "ADMINISTRATIVO")
            {
               TotalADM += Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
            }
        }

        protected void GvSetor_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "ADMINISTRATIVO")
            {

                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = Convert.ToString(TotalADM) + " Min.";
            }
            
        }

Comment: Não cara, havia um erro na forma como você estava fazendo a contagem (soma duplicada). Eu estou vendo agora que seu problema é outro... Procure ser mais preciso, se possível poste um print do erro ou o stack trace!

Comment: Obrigado.
Resolvido de outra forma conforme link.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6752/resultado-diferente-entre-select-apos-aplicar-o-sum-e-o-grop-by/6760?noredirect=1#comment11367_6760